# In R, is there a better way to display descriptive messages that describe your output from a function?

Tags: r, function

## Question:

Is there a more elegant R way to display descriptive messages along with the output of a function?

### This works, but...

...feels pretty amateur:

```
setdiff2 <- function(x, y){
  x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y_name <- deparse(substitute(y))

  list(
    paste("In", x_name, "but not in", y_name, ":"),
    setdiff(x, y),
    paste("In", y_name, "but not in", x_name, ":"),
    setdiff(y, x)
  )
}

vec1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
vec2 <- c("B", "C", "D")
setdiff2(vec1, vec2)
```

```
> setdiff2(vec1, vec2)
[[1]]
[1] "In vec1 but not in vec2 :"

[[2]]
[1] "A"

[[3]]
[1] "In vec2 but not in vec1 :"

[[4]]
[1] "D"
```

I can live with it like it is, but I feel that the list output could look better.  I was kind of hoping to achieve something like this for the output:

```
In vec1 but not in vec2 :
[1] "A"

In vec2 but not in vec1 :
[1] "D"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possibly more than you're asking but the canonical way would be to have your function return a classed object and define a print method for it.  That way you can keep your data object minimal for further downstream use but also have it print nicely.

```
setdiff2 <- function(x, y) {
  x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
  y_name <- deparse(substitute(y))
  
  res <- list(
    xy = list(vars = c(x_name, y_name),
              result = setdiff(x, y)),
    yx = list(vars = c(y_name, x_name),
              result = setdiff(y, x))
  )
  class(res) <- "setdiff2"
  res
}

print.setdiff2 <- function(x) {
  invisible(lapply(x, \(v) {
    cat(sprintf("In %s but not in %s:", v[["vars"]][1], v[["vars"]][2]), sep = "\n")
    print(v[["result"]])
  }))
}

vec1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
vec2 <- c("B", "C", "D")
```

Which gives:

```
setdiff2(vec1, vec2)
In vec1 but not in vec2:
[1] "A"
In vec2 but not in vec1:
[1] "D"
```

And to see the actual object:

```
print.default(setdiff2(vec1, vec2))

$xy
$xy$vars
[1] "vec1" "vec2"

$xy$result
[1] "A"


$yx
$yx$vars
[1] "vec2" "vec1"

$yx$result
[1] "D"


attr(,"class")
[1] "setdiff2"
```

Comment: No, this is good.  I don't have enough experience to know how to do this.  It does exactly what I want to do.  But how does the `setdiff2()` call know to use the second function, `print.setdiff2()`?  I need to go read on that, because I don't understand that part.  This is great, thank you.  I think this would be a fine answer, but I'm going to give it 24 hours to see if any other suggestions appear.

Comment: Take a read [here](https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/s3.html#methods) for an explanation of S3 method dispatch.

Comment: You won’t get a better answer than this. @RitchieSacramento has nailed it.

Comment: @Limey, when I first read Ritchie Sacramento's answer, I was pretty confident this was the answer.  My hesitation comes from reading other SO questions where the OP selected an answer that is clearly the 2nd or 3rd most upvoted answer.   I figure 24hrs is fair for others to weigh-in before I mark it.  I'm so grateful, because I've been trying to up my R game, reading/practicing NSE, but I hadn't (until now) started trying to understand S3 and method dispatch, and this is a great use case.  Thank you all.